# Azure Vnet peering with public IP load balancer

Tags: azure, networking, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer, vnet

I got two Vnets:

Vnet #1: 1 VM with **Public** (internet facing) IP load balancer - internet connected App VMs.

Vnet #2: 3 VMs with **public** (internet facing) IP load balancer - internet and private DB servers (the load balancer is using public ip so that I could access the DBs).

I set up a peering between Vnet1 & Vnet2 so that the communication between them will be private/internal and fast with no internet routing.

I want to access the DBs (using a load balancer) in Vnet2 from Vnet1 - so in the VM located in Vnet1 I use Vnet2 public IP load balancer.

It works...

But the question is - 
**will the communication be routed through the internet or will it be internal?
will Azure route the that internally because the Vnets are peered or should I set up another load balancer with Private IP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the communication be routed through the internet or will it be
>   internal? will Azure route the that internally because the Vnets are
>   peered or should I set up another load balancer with Private IP?

If you want to  route the network traffic through the private network, we should create another load balancer with private IP, then use private IP address to access it.

---

**Update**:

After test in my lab, according to the result, it seems if we use public IP, the traffic network will not be internal.

Here is the tracert **before set peering**:

[image]
[image]

Here is the tracert **after set peering**:

[image]

**14 hops**, same as not set peering, so I think peering will not change the public IP traffic to internal.

By the way, two public IP addresses of Azure, I guess he mean that all traffic will internal, means that public IP traffic will in Azure data centers, will not go to the Internet.

Comment: I used Microsoft support plan to ask a Microsoft expert advice on the subject - he said that when using the public ip, the routing will be internal because of the peering, azure will tell that those resources are peered and will redirect it internally, now I don't know what believe in....

Comment: @Eking Maybe he was right, I will test in my lab tomorrow and give you the result.

Comment: Thank you very much! it sure did help!